# Magento 2 check if invoice has been made for shipment

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, shipment

How to check if the particular item of shipment has invoice or not. In Magento 1.9 the data of shipment was saved in 'sales_flat_invoice_comment'. But in 2.1 there is no link. How to get the information that the specific item of shipment has invoiced or not?

Comment: Do you mean, you need to check Shipment generate for particuler Invoice?

Comment: yes, even for that item of that shipment.

Comment: Which objects / classes do you use in your code? What's the current structure?